# how to show custom message confirm on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a page where I need to show a confirmation with custom text. This is my code and it works fine, but it doesn't show my message. The browser shows a default message, but I don't know why.

```
function unloadPage(){ 
    confirm(" i can't see this message");
    // same result when i try with : return "i can't see this message";
}
window.onbeforeunload = unloadPage;
```

Can anyone explain how to force the browser to take my custom confirm message, and ignore the default browser message?

Comment: is your code reached?

Comment: Have you read [MDN Documentation about beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) ? It contains several usage examples which can be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling the function at `window.onbeforeunload = unloadPage;` it should be `window.onbeforeunload = unloadPage();`

https://jsfiddle.net/speL80sx/

Answer (score 1):

On Page load, You should use `onload` method.

```
window.onload = unloadPage();
   function unloadPage()
   {
   return confirm(" i can see this message");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a return in your function, as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

> The function should assign a string value to the returnValue property
>   of the Event object and return the same string.

```
window.onbeforeunload = myFunction;

myFunction(e) {
    var dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
    e.returnValue = dialogText;
    return dialogText;
};
```

PS. Unfortunately I am not able to test this code at the moment, it is just what I understood from the article.

Answer (score 0):

try this once it will not reload your page without confirming

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are you sure?";
};
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32575454)

Answer (score 0):

For caching reasons, you may wish to avoid `beforeunload` (and `unload`) in favor of `pagehide`.

> The beforeunload event will not make your pages ineligible for bfcache in Chrome or Safari, but it will make them ineligible in Firefox, so avoid using it unless absolutely necessary.

[Source](https://web.dev/bfcache/#only-add-beforeunload-listeners-conditionally)

Example:

```js
window.addEventListener('pagehide', (/* event */) =>
  console.log('pagehide event triggered'))
```